# Numba CUDA ctypes.ArgumentError while calling

Tags: python, numba

I have following code snippet:

```py
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np

@cuda.jit('void (f8[:])')
def inc(a:np.ndarray):
    ind:int = cuda.grid(1)

    if ind < a.shape[0]:
        a[ind]:float += 1

a:np.ndarray = np.zeros(30).astype(float)

t:int = 32
b:int = (a.shape[0] + t - 1) // t

inc[b, t](a)

print(a)
```

and when I executed this script, I got `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`. I don't understand, why I got this exception because `b` is of type `int` and I have installed NVidia CUDA Toolkit. Help me to solve this problem.

**EDITED:**
I got same problem while calling `cuda.is_available()`:

```py
>>> from numba import cuda
>>> cuda.is_available()
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: Leaving aside the missing parenthesis, what do you think `'void (f8[:]'` means?

Comment: `'void (f8[:])'` does not work too, even without calling function first time.

Comment: take a couple of minutes to read the numpy documentation for type signatures. `f8` is 8 byte floating point......

Comment: this function also doesn't work without signature

Comment: Something must be seriously broken in your numpy and numba installations